# How to add two classes in supertype list, PhoneStateListener and AppCompatActivity

Tags: android, kotlin, android-audiomanager, phone-state-listener

Is it possible to add `PhoneStateListener()` with `AppCompatActivity()`? The idea is to create a Phone Call Listener class similar to `class CallListener : AppCompatActivity(), PhoneStateListener() {}`. This errors with "Only one class may appear in a supertype list". I need AppCompatActivity because I need to use an AudioManager and the only way I know how to do that is with `getSystemService()` which isn't availble without AppCompatActivity. I also need the PhoneStateListener to know which state outbound calls are in. What is the correct way to set this up in Kotlin?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can have a custom nested class or concrete class which extends `PhoneStateListener`.

```
class CallListener:PhoneStateListener(){
    override fun onCellInfoChanged(cellInfo: MutableList<CellInfo>?) {
        super.onCellInfoChanged(cellInfo)
    }
}
```

if you need to access context inside this you probably need to pass it in constructor . But if you make it `inner class CallListener` the you can directly use Activity's reference.
make sure you remove all resources of  `PhoneStateListener` in `onStop`or `onDestroy`.
Arrangement with inner class look somewhat like below .

```
 class MyActivity:AppCompatActivity(){
    lateinit var  telephonyManager :TelephonyManager
    lateinit var callListener: CallListener
    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
        telephonyManager = getSystemService(TELEPHONY_SERVICE) as TelephonyManager
        callListener=CallListener()
        telephonyManager.listen(callListener),
    }

    inner class CallListener:PhoneStateListener(){
        override fun onCellInfoChanged(cellInfo: MutableList<CellInfo>?) {
            super.onCellInfoChanged(cellInfo)
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks @ADM. Passing the Context in the constructor seemed to be the easiest solution. In this case, would I still need to remove all resources of PhoneStateListener and if so, what is a good way to do that within onDestroy or onStop?